# Why is both the if and else executed?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

My code is:

```
if [ "$server" == "a" ]; then
        echo "apache"
fi

if [ "$server" ==  "t"   ]
then
        echo "tomcat"
else
        echo "Entered"
fi
```

The value of the `$server` is `t`. I expect the value `tomcat` to be printed on the console. But `Entered` is printed too!

I'm confused about this. How come both the `if` and `else` statements are executed?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure `bash` is interpreting the script?

Comment: If you saw `Entered`, it must have come from a different line in the script, or you looped back to this statement with the value of `server` changed....

Comment: What are U getting if U use `[ "$server" -eq  "t"   ]` ?

Comment: Pretty sure `-eq` is for integer comparison only.

Comment: @MRSrinivas: I'm getting only `tomcat` when I use `[ "$server" -eq "t" ]`

Comment: have you tried `[ "X$server" = "Xt" ]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The else branch should only ever execute if the preceding if statement evaluates to false. There's not really any exceptions to that rule that I'm aware of. There's probably something else fishy going on in the bash file that's causing the issue.

Make sure bash is what is executing the script. `#!/bin/bash` should be on the first line.

Answer (score 5):

To solve your problem, do something like this:

- Put echo statements into every branch:

  ```
  if [ "$server" == "a" ]; then
      echo "in branch apache"
      echo "apache"
  fi

  if [ "$server" ==  "t"   ]
  then
          echo "in branch tomact"
          echo "tomcat"
  else
          echo "in else branch"
          echo "Entered"
  fi
  ```

If you still can't spot the problem, one of these:

- Execute the script by using the `-x` flag

  ```
  bash -x <scriptname>
  ```
- Comment out every line... then comment in line by line and see what result you get