# Why does this conditional return "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

My conditional works properly when the dirs exist, but if they don't, it seems to execute both `then` and `else` statements (is that the correct term?).

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(find path/to/dir/*[^thisdir] -type d -maxdepth 0) ]]
  then
    find path/to/dir/*[^thisdir] -type d -maxdepth 0 -exec mv {} new/location \;
    echo "Huzzah!"
  else
    echo "hey hey hey"
fi
```

**prompt**
For the first call, the dirs are there; in the second, they've been moved from the first call.

```
$ sh script.sh
Huzzah!
$ sh script.sh
find: path/to/dir/*[^thisdir]: No such file or directory
hey hey hey
```

How can I fix this?

**tried suggestion(s)**

```
if [[ -d $(path/to/dir/*[^thisdir]) ]]
  then
    find path/to/dir/*[^thisdir] -type d -maxdepth 0 -exec mv {} statamic-1.3-personal/admin/themes \;
    echo "Huzzah!"
  else
    echo "hey hey hey"
fi
```

result

```
$ sh script.sh
script.sh: line 1: path/to/dir/one_of_the_dirs_to_be_moved: is a directory
hey hey hey
```

Comment: You *tried suggestion* was near right, but need to keep out `$()`, and have to reach `...dir/!(thisdir)` instead of `*[^thisdr]`. But this would work only if path/to/dir/*[^thisdir] match exactly **one** entry. Take a look at my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is probably occurring at `if [[ $(find path/to/dir/*[^thisdir] -type d -maxdepth 0) ]]` and then it goes to else because find errors out.

`find` wants its directory parameter to exist. Based on what you are trying to do you should probably consider

```
$(find path/to/dir/ -name "appropriate name pattern" -type d -maxdepth 1)
```

Also, I'd consider using actual logical function in `if`. See [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) for file conditionals.

Comment: Your first suggestion didn't work out. Same results as before. The second (logical function in if) makes sense, but I must be doing something wrong with that. I'll update the question with that info.

Comment: with -d option you don't need $(). You are basically trying to execute every directory. Should be something like `[[ -d path/to/dir/whatever`. However, I never used *[^thisdir] pattern. What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: ended up using `find path/to/dir/*  \! -name 'this_dir_stays_put' -type d -maxdepth 0 -exec mv {} new/location \;` the intent of the post wasn't to solve my problem, but to understand why this didn't solve my problem. Alex was right, the error was in what I did with find in the conditional.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be some errors:

First, the pattern `path/to/dir/*[^thisdir]` is interpreted in bash in the same manner than `path/to/dir/*[^dihstr]` mean *all filename ending by `d`, `i`, `h`, `s`, `t` **or** `r`.

Than if you are searching for something in **this** dir (`path/to/dir`) but not on `path/to/dir/thisdir`, **and not on a nth subdir**, you could bannish `find` and write:

**Edit:** There was an error on my sample too: `[ -e $var ]` was wrong.

```
declare -a files=( path/to/dir/!(thisdir) )
if [ -e $files ] ;then
    mv -t newlocation "${files[@]}"
    echo "Huzzah!"
else
    echo "hey hey hey"
fi
```

If you need `find` for searching in subirs, please give us samples and/or more descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `#!/bin/bash` on the first line to ensure that it is bash that is executing your script, as recommended by this post:

[Why is both the if and else executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986561/why-is-both-the-if-and-else-executed)

Comment: Already have that, left it out for simplicity, but realize maybe I shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wishes to move all files excluding *thisdir* to a new location.

A solution using `find` would be to exclude `thisdir` using `find`'s functionality, rather than by using `bash`'s shell expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(find path/to/directory/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -not -name 'thisdir') ]]
    then
        find path/to/directory/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -not -name 'thisdir' -exec mv {} new/location \;
        echo "Huzzah!"
    else
        echo "hey hey hey"
fi
```

This has been tested, and works under `bash` version 4.2.39, and GNU findutils v4.5.10.